# Posting to Wordpress Rest API fails to work in Python

Tags: python, wordpress

Cannot seem to find nor create a minimum working example of posting an article to the REST API. I have the following set up and code.

```
import requests
import json
import base64

user = 'NASA'
password = 'bah bah ...'
url = 'http://any.com/wp-json/wp/v2'

data_sauth = user + ':' + password

post = {
        'title': 'Rubbish',
        'slug': 'rest-api-1',
        'status': 'publish',
        'content': 'random stuff',
        'excerpt': 'lala',
        'format': 'standard'
        }

token = base64.standard_b64encode(data_sauth.encode())
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8'), 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}


r = requests.post(url + '/posts', headers=headers, json=post)
print(r.status_code)
print(json.loads(r.content))
```

Now I get a 200 code. But I just get no post appearing and return of the posts. I cannot find where this might be going wrong. The API reference is here: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#create-a-post

On the WP side, I have installed the plugin named Application Passwords and ensured that the credentials match. No post appears, I get a 200 status code, and get a poll from the WP site of the existing posts, but no new post.

Comment: Are posts not appearing on website or only in _print(json.loads(r.content))_?

Comment: @Tino, no posts are appearing and just a post query appears to be performed on the end point. Not quite what is expected.

Comment: can you update your question with the server output body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is super old but I tried your code with my credentials and it worked perfectly, check that you're requesting to the right URL (some sites have different URLs for the API).